# A Delivery Drone

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, navigation, gps, ardupilot

I'm building a delivery drone as my final year project. A drone that can deliver a package to offices around my small town autonomously, for my final year project.

I would like to know how this drone can find the exact location of these offices, since I couldn't find them on Google map?

Comment: if you cannot find the location of the office, then the drone will not be able to find the location either ... the receiver of the delivery would have to either provide the location of the delivery or provide some kind of a beacon that the drone could find

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have the knowledge of how beacons work and the implementation. Or where I can learn?

Comment: i do not have the necessary knowledge .... i think that an accurate beacon recognition system is probably a final year project in itself

Comment: Seriously? That's a complex one

Comment: You need to build a database (basically what you hoped Google Maps would provide) of office addresses vs. GPS coordinates.

Comment: You do realize that to do this legally in the US (and probably most other western countries) you need all sorts of hard-to-get permits, right?  You could get by in the US if you have line-of-sight control of the aircraft at all time, but you'd be pushing the envelope (I think just having a transmitter that you could use to override your drone would work, as long as you can see the drone as it works).

Comment: You could create a database of the GPS location of the these offices.

Comment: Drones aren't magic. If they can't find the office then neither can you.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the outdoor drones use GPS for autonomous navigation. Even the flight controllers like Ardupilot and Naza need to be given the GPS coordinates of the destination for autonomous flights. The best way to do this is go to the exact location and get the GPS coordinates and then program the flight controller.

Apart from this approach there are image and point cloud based approaches to localize the drones but they are a bit complex methods and require a considerable time to implement.

Comment: How those the image and point cloud approach work?

Comment: @Will like human vision